# How to make a funtion of togglebutton in toolbar android

Tags: android

I need to place two icon to make a funtion of togglebutton in toolbar android, for this I have created two icons in the menu:

```
<item
   android:id="@+id/action_connect_off"
   android:icon="@drawable/enchufe_off"
   android:orderInCategory="103"
   android:title="Item"
   app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
   android:id="@+id/action_connect_on"
   android:icon="@drawable/enchufe_on"
   android:orderInCategory="103"
   android:title="Item"
   app:showAsAction="always"
   android:visible="false"/>
```

And in my MainActivity I have:

```
Boolean flagConection = false;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_connect_off) {
        flagConection = true;
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_connect_on) {
        flagConection = false;
        return true;
    }

   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem IconOFF = menu.findItem(R.id.action_connect_off);
    MenuItem IconON = menu.findItem(R.id.action_connect_on);

    if (flagConection){
        IconOFF.setVisible(false);
        IconON.setVisible(true);
   }
    else {
        IconOFF.setVisible(true);
        IconON.setVisible(false);
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

but I can't make it work, every time I press the icon action_connect_off it is detected but the icon does not change state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to signal to the system that the options menu's state needs to be updated. Add a call to either `invalidateOptionsMenu()` or `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` any time you modify `flagConection`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_connect_off) {
        flagConection = true;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_connect_on) {
        flagConection = false;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        return true;
    }

   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```